# convergence of the series $\sum ^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\sin k \sin \sqrt{k}}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

convergence of the series $\sum ^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\sin k \sin \sqrt{k}}{k}$.

I know that

$\sum_{k= 1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin k}k$ convergence but how to prove this series..

Comment: Use summation by parts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: If needed refer to my answer here; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298918/bound-for-partial-sums-of-the-form-sinn-sin-sqrtn/4299824#4299824